# pandas read_sql using Django.db.connection

Tags: django, pandas

Is there a recommended way to utilize pandas read_sql from within a Django app? I was using a much older version of pandas and this worked:

```
import django.db.connection
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_sql("select employee.name from employee;", con=connection)
```

Now, I'm getting this error from read_sql:

```
UserWarning: pandas only supports SQLAlchemy connectable (engine/connection) or database string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connection. Other DBAPI2 objects are not tested. Please consider using SQLAlchemy.
```

The query seems to work even with the warning but I don't want to take chances that it might break.  I was using the Django.db.connection so that pandas makes use of the db connection pooling within Django.  I can successfully use a connection string with the read_sql method but I don't want pandas opening up a bunch of connections in a multi-user system. Same with SQLAlchemy - I don't want to add another connection pool into the app.  Any advice or workarounds?  I haven't found anything in the pandas or Django documentation covering this.

```
Django==3.2
pandas==2.2.1
mysqlclient==2.2.4
MySQL version 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using MySQL, your Django settings should be something this:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypass',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

You can use these settings to create a SQLAlchemy engine to use.

```py
from django.conf import settings
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(
    "mysql://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{name}".format(
        user=settings.DATABASES["default"]["USER"],
        password=settings.DATABASES["default"]["PASSWORD"],
        host=settings.DATABASES["default"]["HOST"],
        port=settings.DATABASES["default"]["PORT"],
        name=settings.DATABASES["default"]["NAME"],
    )
)

df = pd.read_sql("SELECT employee.name FROM employee", con=engine)
```

Good luck!

Comment: Wouldn't that create an additional db connection pool through SQLAlchemy? I am wanting to use the existing Django db connection pool with pandas if possible .

Comment: Are you really at the scale where this is a concern? Remember, "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." To answer your question: yes, it would create another connection. And often, you can do `from django.db import connection; df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT a FROM B", connection)`, but I don't know about MySQL. Only SQLite is officially supported in that fashion, but I've done it in PostgreSQL and ignored the warning. There's also `django-pandas`, which offers methods for creating dataframes from Django querysets if you build a model around your destination table.